# Problems inserting MessageBox with option to cancel closing file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a prompt to remind the user to export the file before closing it.  My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Response As Long

    Response = MsgBox("If changes have been made to this file without running the Monthly Claim Program, you MUST run the 'Export to Mastersheet' program.  If you have not yet exported the file, please press NO, and do so.  Otherwise, press YES to close this file", vbYesNo)
    If Response = vbNo Then
       Cancel = True
    Else

    End If
    Call Remove_Macros_Menu
End Sub
```

However, no matter if I choose True or False for the Cancel function, the file closes.  Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Works for me, what does Remove_Macros_Menu do? does it close the WB? If so you want it in the Else block

Answer (score 0):

Kathy,

Is the code in the ThisWorkbook module?  It needs to be there, otherwise it won't do anything.  Also, assuming the Remove_Macros_Menu deletes a custom menu for this workbook, I think you want the line that calls it inside the Else clause, especially if a button to export the code is in that menu.  Otherwise you'll be deleting the menu even if they press no

Be aware of a flaw in deleting menus in the BeforeClose event, namely if the workbook is unsaved the user will see the "Save, Don't Save, Cancel" menu.  If they choose Cancel the Close is cancelled, but your menu is still deleted.

Comment: The code is in the ThisWorkbook module. This code will work on some computers on our network, and not others. It's very strange. In terms of the Remove_Macros_Menu code, where do you suggest I put it?

Comment: Kathy, do the computers all have macros enabled?  Can you run other macros on the computers this doesn't work on? 
I put my MakeMenu and DeleteMenu routines in the WorkbookActivate and WorkbookDeactivate procedures (or sometimes in the analogous Worksheet events).  This has the added advantage that your menus only show when the workbook they belong to is active.